# Sprout Forms: empty phone field still shows error "Phone is invalid. Example format: (506) 234-5678"

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Running Craft CMS 3.3.20 and Sprout Forms Pro 3.6.8

- form has Phone field
- submit form with no value in Phone field
- form reloads with error message "Phone is invalid. Example format: (506) 234-5678"

If valid phone number entered form submits fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug and is resolved in release Sprout Forms v3.6.9 and Sprout Fields v3.5.2.

---

Original Reply:

> This is a bug in Sprout Forms v3.6.8. We'll have a fix out for this shortly and I'll update this comment when we do.